# AMD graphics card not showing in device manager on windows 10

Tags: windows, amd-radeon, brightness

I bought a new hp laptop from e-commerce site "Snapdeal". Model is "HP 15 ba025au". It has AMD Raedon R4 integrated graphics. Since it had free DOS pre installed, I immediately installed Windows 10 pro 64 bit. I had already downloaded drivers from HP site. So after W10 installation, I installed some drivers such as AMD HD graphics, Realtech sound, Realtech wireless LAN. Everything was going fine then I tried to lower the screen brightness, I tried from hotkeys i.e. f7. But nothing happened, the screen brightness didn't go down. I tried from power control option. It shows the value like 25%, 50%.. but brightness remains constant. I googled the issue 'n find one solution that is to update the driver under "display adapter" under "device manager". But when I went to "display adapter", I found  my amd graphics driver is not listed there. I can only find "Microsoft basic display adapter". Then I realized my graphics driver was not working. I reinstalled it but the problem persisted. Then i read somewhere graphics driver doesn't work if graphics card is not there. But my notebook has the aforesaid graphics card. Then why it is not listed in device manager? How can I fix this issue so that my brightness control works properly. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've installed the drivers from the following site
http://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-15-Notebook-PC-series/10862317/model/12206081

The related files you need are

1. AMD High-Definition (HD) Graphics Driver
2. HP System Event Utility

Ensure you've installed them both.

The System Event Utility requires particular Drivers for it to function as recommended by HP.

Then Follow the steps below

1. Go to "Device Manager"
2. Under "Display Adapters" Right Click "Microsoft Basic Adapter"
3. Select "Update Driver Software"
4. Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
5. Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"

You Should now see a list of compatible drivers.

6. Ensure "Show Compatible hardware" is ticked and Select the AMD Driver as mentioned in your spec.
7. Click "Next". 
   Your screen may go blank for a few seconds and return.

If there are further issues with the display after changing the driver, then it may be possible that your graphics card has an issue, which is why the driver may have defaulted to the Microsoft one.

Comment: in the list of compatible drivers, I can only find the Microsoft basic display adapter 'n nothing 'n yes  show compatible hardware is also ticked. Please tell me now what should I do? Should I return it or go to a service center. Please please reply..

Comment: That means you've not installed the AMD High-Definition (HD) Graphics Driver correctly. Go to programs and Features-> remove the AMD Driver and reinstall it.